# Is the following about appearance differences in the English and German versions true?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

A friend of mine said that, in the English version of Star Wars 7 at least, voices or even whole scenes involving the following persons appear that don't appear in the German version:

> Yoda and Obi Wan

Although from what I understood it is in the Force vision.....and there at least in the German version the voice could not be really understood as it was way too quiet in relation to the other sounds happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are almost certainly some differences between the English and German versions, with relation to those characters, but I don't think it's anything like what you're imagining. There are no scenes with those characters in them that could have been removed, despite what your friend seems to be telling you.

Obi-Wan and Yoda are never on-screen in the movie. Rather, Frank Oz and Ewan McGregor, along with clips of Alec Guiness from previous movies, were used to [add voice-overs](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/star-wars-the-force-awakens-obi-wan-yoda-1201666121/) to a particular dream/flashback-type sequence in the movie.

In a non-English version, obviously these would have to be dubbed over by a German (or whatever language) speaker, but since only the voices were heard to begin with, this would basically eliminate Yoda and Obi-Wan's "real voices" from the movie.

Even if it's true, don't worry, you aren't really missing much beyond an interesting Easter-Egg. You have to be paying really close attention in the English version to even notice.

Comment: [article about the voice cameos](http://variety.com/2015/film/news/star-wars-the-force-awakens-obi-wan-yoda-1201666121/)

Comment: So their voices ARE there in the english version but are hard to hear? (if so then it could be the same in the german one and I just overheard them twice)

Comment: they have a total of 2 lines between the three of them, admists a lot of other noise, etc. but if you're paying attention you definitely hear at least part of it.

Comment: tnx that means then I just overheard it (had troubles even making out a voice anyway in that one scene^^)